# google script how to set the form with respondent can see

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

[image]

Inside the image, we can have the check box for about the respondent can see "Miss questions, correct answers, point values".

How can I access these options with google script?
What exact command should I use?
I tried searching in this google [google support](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form) page.

E.g. If I want to collect email, we can have something like:

```
form.setCollectEmail(true)
```

Comment: Have you tried [setIsQuizEnabled()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setisquizenabled) ? Also [see](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#setscorescore)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing it as the documentation for the [`setIsQuiz(enabled)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setisquizenabled) states:

> Quiz settings are only available in the new Forms UI; making a form a
>   Quiz will opt the form into using the new UI.

You can create a feature request on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) in order to let Google know about it.

Comment: I had this problem as well and submitted it on the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171493233).  Please star it if you think it's a good idea.